# Cannot find SQL Developer application file after installing sql developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had Installed JDK8 and also SQL Developer , but i can't find the executable file of SQL Developer.

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SQL Developer doesn't have an 'installer' - just a zip file.

You basically unzip/extract the archive to a new folder, say in C:\oracle\sqldev (totally arbitrary), and in that root/top level directory, you'll see a sqldeveloper.exe that you can run.

So if I unzip my download to c:...\19.2.1 - I would see the EXE

[image]

If you're on a Mac, you should 'drag' the SQLDeveloper.app to your Applications 'folder' in Finder, then just launch it like any other program on your machine.

Comment: ,yes I did the same thing bro. But I can't see that sqldeveloper.exe

Comment: I have no idea what you did, 'bro' because all you said was you 'installed SQL Developer' - what EXACTLY did you do?

Comment: First of all I installed jdk 8 in my machine , and next I downloaded and extracted SQL developer to some folder in my Desktop, and then I can't see the executable file

Comment: In the screenshot provided by you , all the folders are extracted to my machine expect that executable file

Comment: then your zip is corrupt or something prevented all the files from coming out...delete the folder on your desktop and do the extract again - using native windows Explorer